# xcopy command does not work in a batch file

Tags: windows, windows-8, batch-file, xcopy

The command below works in CMD Prompt, but does not work in a batch file.

```
xcopy "D:\Desenvolvimento\Repositórios GIT\driverXD\app\*" driverxd\ /e
```

Comment: the destination is a relative path, maybe that could be the cause?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the acute accent over o in Repositórios. This requires you to either save the batch file in a correct character encoding or by setting correct character encoding in the batch-file like the following:

```
chcp 1252
xcopy "D:\Desenvolvimento\Repositórios GIT\driverXD\app\*" driverxd\ /e
```

1252 references [Windows 1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) which is the normal latin encoding.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to use the START command in batch files, so it would look something like:

> START XCOPY <.path> <.switches>

Comment: AGH, that spawns a new temporary shell, which is pretty undesirable in a for loop.